# Get ID of object in GridFS

Tags: gridfs

When querying MongoDB, the `_id` is always returned. However, this does not appear to be the case for GridFS. How do I get the object ID of an object in GridFS?

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from gridfs import GridFS

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['test']
fs = GridFS(db)

fs.put(b"{'a': 1}", _id=1234)
fs.put(b"{'a': 2}", _id=5678)

query = {'_id': {'$in': [1234, 5678]}}

documents = fs.find(query)
# [b"{'a': 1}", b"{'a': 2}"]  No IDs!
```